# "No such file or directory" under node_modules, react native while installing app on Android

Tags: android, node.js, react-native, npm

I created my new project in React Native and when I tried to run the app on Android using the command

```
npm run android
```

I got the below issues, I couldn't figure out where the problems are lying:

```
/Users/.../ProjectName/node_modules/.bin/launchPackager.command ; exit;
/Users/.../ProjectName/node_modules/.bin/.packager.env: line 2: export: `Projects/ProjectName': not a valid identifier
/Users/.../ProjectName/node_modules/.bin/.packager.env: line 3: export: `Projects/ProjectName/node_modules/react-native: not a valid identifier
/Users/.../ProjectName/node_modules/.bin/launchPackager.command: line 4: cd: /Users/.../Documents/My: No such file or directory
/Users/.../ProjectName/node_modules/.bin/launchPackager.command: line 5: /Users/.../Documents/My/cli.js: No such file or directory
Process terminated. Press <enter> to close the window
```

I tried re-creating new project again and again but always get the above issues while running into project. Below versions are installed on my PC:

- HomeBrew: "4.1.13"
- ReactNative: "0.72.5
- React: "18.2.0"
- NPM: "9.8.1"
- Node: "v18.18.0"
- Ruby: "2.6.10"

Please do help me to run my project, Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

To Resolve the “export not a valid identifier” Problem

```
export PATH = $PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

Run the below commands.

```
rm -rf node_modules 
rm -rf package-lock.json
npm install
```